# How to search more complex list items in pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

At the moment, I am trying to make a search field for a project using javascript and for some reason my search code is not working. I attribute this to the complexity of the list items, to this point, what would be the proper Javascript code to search the H3 tags in the list below:

```
 <ul class="results" list-style: none>
        <li class="result">
            <div class="container">
                    <div class='headline'>
                        <h3>a list item</h3>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="result">
            <div class="container">
                    <div class='headline'>
                        <h3>a list item 2</h3>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="result">
            <div class="container">
                    <div class='headline'>
                        <h3>a list item 3</h3>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be better definition of: "*I attribute this to the complexity of the list items, to this point, what would be the proper Javascript code to search the H3 tags in the list below:"*

Most basic search:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('h3'); // -> returning a nodelist with all the h3 elements in the dom
```

If you need to add more "complexity" then just change the selector in ('selector')

**Otherwise please edit your question to be more precise what you want, like an example output.**

**UPDATE:**

So if I understood correctly what you meant then a very very general example to just demonstrate what i guessing you mean

```js
const getH3 = document.querySelectorAll('ul.results h3'); // here we get all the h3 inside the ul

// let us assume that in our "seach box" the term was '2' for example
const term = '2';

// what to do now? Since we got all our h3 already inside a const we can just go through all of them to check if the term is there, like for example with a forEach

// also creating here an array to push in all the matches
let matches = [];
getH3.forEach(h3 => {
      if (h3.textContent.includes(term)) matches.push(h3); // here we push in if our search term was found inside the textContent of an h3 using the string method "includes"
      // ofc you can also directly just push the found textContent or also both .-.
});

console.log(matches); // output: [h3]
console.log(matches[0].textContent); // output: a list item 2
```

**UPDATE 2**
so this should then answer general questions on this topic:

here the code with comments:

```js
// for simplicity i will stick with the example from before with my 2 since its a pretty simple term :)
    // so we doing the same things as before but with some modification

    const getH3 = document.querySelectorAll('ul.results h3'); // keep in mind that this script should be executed
    // after the dom loaded, otherwise getH3 will be [] empty

    // getting our input field which i added to the html with the id
    const search = document.getElementById('search'); // here the same with the loading

    // so now we have several ways to make our "searching" for probably all ways we need some event
    // this could be everytime we type something or when we click on a button etc.
    // we will use the "input" or "change" event

    // so adding the Eventlistener, could be achieved in two ways, i will use the addEventListener method
    search.addEventListener('input', () => {
        // everytime there is an input in the input element this function will be called

        // since you dont need to work with the element, we dont need to save what we found, we will just make them the only ones left on the screen

        // this can be achieved (in my opinion!) with giving or removing a class which makes them disappear or appear
        // so we added a small css class with display:none

        // now again we go through all h3

        // so now it gets a bit weird since we used the h3, i will explain the other way underneath
        getH3.forEach(h3 => {
            if (h3.textContent.includes(search.value)) { // if the h3 should be displayed
                h3.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove('invis') // dom traversing to the li element which holds the h3 to remove the class in case it was there

            } else { // if the h3 shouldnt be displayed
                h3.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.add('invis') // adding the class to the li so it disappear
            }
        });

        /*
        alternative we could also go through all the li or just use document.querySelector('ul.results>li')
        to get all the li
        like:
        const getLi = document.querySelectorAll('ul.results>li');

        getLi.forEach(li =>{
            ...
        })
        */
    })
```

in html added on top the ul:

```html
<input id="search" type="text"> <!-- search box -->
```

And in css the class:

```css
.invis {
      display: none;
}
```

and here a example snippet you can run yourself to see how it works now:

```js
const getH3 = document.querySelectorAll('ul.results h3');

        const search = document.getElementById('search');

        search.addEventListener('input', () => {
            getH3.forEach(h3 => {
                if (h3.textContent.includes(search.value)) h3.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove('invis');
                else h3.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.add('invis');
            });
        })
```

```css
.invis {
     display: none;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Searching</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="search" type="text"> <!-- search box -->
    <ul class="results" list-style: none>
        <li class="result">
            <div class="container">
                <div class='headline'>
                    <h3>a list item</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="result">
            <div class="container">
                <div class='headline'>
                    <h3>a list item 2</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="result">
            <div class="container">
                <div class='headline'>
                    <h3>a list item 3</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: My apologies, the more specific output I am looking for is the ability to filter the "results" using a search box on the basis of the terms inside the <h3> tags. So eg: search input = "test", show the li with the h3 containing that value

Comment: @developer_dude is the updated version helpful?

Comment: Thank you, the updated version was helpful, the only question I still have is how I can use this script to hide a specific list item (for example if 2 is not in the term, that list item is hidden from results). It would also be helpful to know how to link a search box "input" to this script- sorry for the multitude of questions, I am fairly new to Javascript.

Comment: @developer_dude hope its now what you wanted :) if yes then mark it as the right answer

Comment: Thank you, that was the correct answer, and again thanks for all of your help. The one other question I have is how could I take these list items and make javascript render them for a number of variables: Eg: For Variable in variables: create list item....which I am aware is in no syntax- just trying to keep it simple- and again sorry for all of the questions.

Comment: @developer_dude please maybe edit your question or give me a small example, because i dont really understand the question. Maybe you asking how to make javascript render these li by looking into some stored data and checking there if there is a h3 content that fits and then rendering that in the dom?

Comment: I think that makes sense to me, again, sorry for all of the questions- you've been a big help.